# RGBDSLAM Problem Hydro

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Linux 12.04 and ROS Hydro
I am trying to install package rgbdslam but got some errors. Can any one tell what am I doing wrong? after executing  rosmake rgbdslam_freiburg I get this:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rgbdslam_freiburg']                       
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/wilk/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140127-004513
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rgbdslam_freiburg'] to:
['rgbdslam']                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin
 No Makefile in package catkin
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
 No Makefile in package cpp_common
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package rospack
 No Makefile in package rospack
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg
 No Makefile in package genmsg
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
 No Makefile in package rostime
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
 No Makefile in package xmlrpcpp
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
 No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genpy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> gencpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< genlisp ROS_NOBUILD in package genlisp
 No Makefile in package genlisp
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genpy ROS_NOBUILD in package genpy
 No Makefile in package genpy
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< gencpp ROS_NOBUILD in package gencpp
 No Makefile in package gencpp
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
 No Makefile in package rosunit
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> message_generation [ make ]                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
 No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
 No Makefile in package roscpp_traits
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< message_generation ROS_NOBUILD in package message_generation
 No Makefile in package message_generation
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> console_bridge [ make ]                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
 No Makefile in package rosgraph
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
 No Makefile in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> message_runtime [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean
 No Makefile in package rosclean
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< console_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package console_bridge
 No Makefile in package console_bridge
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< message_runtime ROS_NOBUILD in package message_runtime
 No Makefile in package message_runtime
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam
 No Makefile in package rosparam
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> class_loader [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
 No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster
 No Makefile in package rosmaster
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> actionlib_msgs [ make ]                                
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles
 No Makefile in package angles
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< class_loader ROS_NOBUILD in package class_loader
 No Makefile in package class_loader
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
 No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib
 No Makefile in package pluginlib
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< actionlib_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package actionlib_msgs
 No Makefile in package actionlib_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
 No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
 No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> tf2_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond
 No Makefile in package bond
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib
 No Makefile in package smclib
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
 No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< tf2_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package tf2_msgs
 No Makefile in package tf2_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
 No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> tf2 [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp
 No Makefile in package bondcpp
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< tf2 ROS_NOBUILD in package tf2
 No Makefile in package tf2
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> tf2_py [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet
 No Makefile in package nodelet
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
 No Makefile in package rosout
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_msgs
 No Makefile in package pcl_msgs
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< tf2_py ROS_NOBUILD in package tf2_py
 No Makefile in package tf2_py
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl_conversions [ make ]                               
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch68 Complete ]
 No Makefile in package roslaunch
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_conversions
 No Makefile in package pcl_conversions
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2
 No Makefile in package opencv2
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_srvs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_srvs
 No Makefile in package std_srvs
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest
 No Makefile in package rostest
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< nav_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package nav_msgs
 No Makefile in package nav_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> actionlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge
 No Makefile in package cv_bridge
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> octomap_msgs [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< actionlib ROS_NOBUILD in package actionlib
 No Makefile in package actionlib
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> octomap [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools
 No Makefile in package topic_tools
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters
 No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf2_ros [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf2_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package tf2_ros
 No Makefile in package tf2_ros
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make ]                            
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag
 No Makefile in package rosbag
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< octomap_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package octomap_msgs
 No Makefile in package octomap_msgs
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< octomap ROS_NOBUILD in package octomap
 No Makefile in package octomap
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostopic [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< visualization_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package visualization_msgs
 No Makefile in package visualization_msgs
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostopic ROS_NOBUILD in package rostopic
 No Makefile in package rostopic
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmsg
 No Makefile in package rosmsg
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosnode [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice
 No Makefile in package rosservice
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosnode ROS_NOBUILD in package rosnode
 No Makefile in package rosnode
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
 No Makefile in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roswtf ROS_NOBUILD in package roswtf
 No Makefile in package roswtf
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
 No Makefile in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
 No Makefile in package tf
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros
 No Makefile in package pcl_ros
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> octomap_ros [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< octomap_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package octomap_ros
 No Makefile in package octomap_ros
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> octomap_server [ make ]                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< octomap_server ROS_NOBUILD in package octomap_servere ]
 No Makefile in package octomap_server
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rgbdslam [ make ]                                      
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesbdslam: 17.0 sec ]          [ 1 Active 67/68 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  make[3]: *** Oczekiwanie na niezakończone zadania....
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/openni_listener.cpp.o] Błąd 1
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Błąd 1
  /home/wilk/hydro_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/node.cpp: In constructor ‘Node::Node(const cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&, const CameraInfoConstPtr&, std_msgs::Header, cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector>, cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor>)’:
  /home/wilk/hydro_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/node.cpp:76:20: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘((Node*)this)->Node::pc_col.boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator-> [with T = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>]()->pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::header = depth_header’
  /home/wilk/hydro_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/node.cpp:76:20: note: candidate is:
  /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/PCLHeader.h:16:10: note: pcl::PCLHeader& pcl::PCLHeader::operator=(const pcl::PCLHeader&)
  /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/PCLHeader.h:16:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std_msgs::Header’ to ‘const pcl::PCLHeader&’
  /home/wilk/hydro_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/node.cpp: In constructor ‘Node::Node(cv::Mat, cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector>, cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor>, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr, cv::Mat)’:
  /home/wilk/hydro_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/node.cpp:169:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘tf::StampedTransform::StampedTransform(const tf::Transform&, uint64_t&, std::basic_string<char>, std::string&)’
  /home/wilk/hydro_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/node.cpp:169:26: note: candidates are:
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:91:3: note: tf::StampedTransform::StampedTransform()
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:91:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:87:3: note: tf::StampedTransform::StampedTransform(const tf::Transform&, const ros::Time&, const string&, const string&)
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:87:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ to ‘const ros::Time&’
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:81:7: note: tf::StampedTransform::StampedTransform(const tf::StampedTransform&)
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:81:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
  /home/wilk/hydro_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/node.cpp:169:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘tf::StampedTransform::StampedTransform(const tf::Transform&, uint64_t&, std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>)’
  /home/wilk/hydro_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/node.cpp:169:26: note: candidates are:
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:91:3: note: tf::StampedTransform::StampedTransform()
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:91:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:87:3: note: tf::StampedTransform::StampedTransform(const tf::Transform&, const ros::Time&, const string&, const string&)
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:87:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ to ‘const ros::Time&’
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:81:7: note: tf::StampedTransform::StampedTransform(const tf::StampedTransform&)
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:81:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
  /home/wilk/hydro_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/node.cpp:169:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘tf::StampedTransform::StampedTransform(const tf::Transform&, uint64_t&, const char [17], std::string&)’
  /home/wilk/hydro_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/node.cpp:169:26: note: candidates are:
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:91:3: note: tf::StampedTransform::StampedTransform()
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:91:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 4 provided
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:87:3: note: tf::StampedTransform::StampedTransform(const tf::Transform&, const ros::Time&, const string&, const string&)
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:87:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ to ‘const ros::Time&’
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:81:7: note: tf::StampedTransform::StampedTransform(const tf::StampedTransform&)
  /opt/ros/hydro/include/tf/transform_datatypes.h:81:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 4 provided
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/node.cpp.o] Błąd 1
  make[3]: Opuszczenie katalogu `/home/wilk/hydro_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Błąd 2
  make[2]: Opuszczenie katalogu `/home/wilk/hydro_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Błąd 2
  make[1]: Opuszczenie katalogu `/home/wilk/hydro_workspace/sandbox/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rgbdslam written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/wilk/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140127-004513/rgbdslam/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rgbdslam [FAIL] [ 17.08 seconds ]                      
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rgbdslam. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 68 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/wilk/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140127-004513
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122541/rgbdslam-problem-hydro/) by [Wilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7921/wilk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2014-01-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Michiel](https://answers.ros.org/users/11396/michiel/) on 2014-01-29**:
I have the same problem. Any update on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yea... I think I meshed up my hydro system and maby it's good idea to start from 0... but I don’t know how defectively uninstall it.
So what I did was: backup all my data on other drive, re installation of linux and then installation of fuerte.

---

Originally posted by [Wilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7921/wilk/) with karma: 67 on 2014-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0